# Redirect to Google Calendar Add Event

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a simple way where i could use Javascript to let user to add system's events to their Google Calendar event? What i need to accomplish here is, when the user clicks on the event on the calendar, there will be a popup that prompt user to sign in to Google (OAuth 2.0), and then the user will be redirected to the Google page for creating event. While the event's data that the user will add, is sent through Javascript. I use Fullcalendar from https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.6.1 .
I have already go through the fullcalendar.io docs and i cannot found how to do this.
Any link for my reference? I need that API from Google that allow me to do this.

Comment: "redirected to the Google page for creating event." Well you could do that, but the user would have to re-type the data. What you're perhaps looking for is the Google Calendar API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/), which lets you manipulate calendar data programatically without using the Google GUI. User could use fullCalendar as the GUI and then you write code to send it to Google in the background via the API when they select an event. The only thing the user has to do is log into their account first.

Comment: But there's no "simple" solution for this, you'd have to write the integration code yourself (unless some kind person has written such a tool already to integrate with Google / FullCalendar, perhaps you can google it). Basically you'd just handle eventClick in fullCalendar, and then call the Google API via ajax - for which there are JS libraries provided and samples in the API documentation. So it's not "simple" but I wouldn't say it was particularly "hard" either. If you have a problem with it the post your attempt here so someone can help you fix it.

Comment: You answered my question but that link you shared is already visited and i cannot find the guide there. There is only an 'events.insert' api which i had been using. But that is adding programmatically, not popping up a dialog to Google's event creating page.

Comment: Why would you want to pop it up to the create event page? I already said that's not a good way to do it. Even if you redirect the user to the right page,  1) there's no way to auto-insert the data into the input fields in that page (because that would require a script injection attack on that page), and 2) even if you solved that, it's a completely unnecessary step for the user to have to do, to confirm it, when you could just insert the data directly into their calendar for them, with no effort required. I can't see why you'd even want to do it that way, it just makes extra work for everyone.

Comment: Because my client wants it that way. If there is really no way i can do that, i guess i will just create my own dialog that popping up and prompt for user confirmation and programmatically uses the calendar.events.insert API.

Comment: That's the only way to do it. Sometimes you just have to tell the client that what they're asking is impossible in exactly the way the described. But if you find a way to do it which is just as neat then they won't mind. You might find they didn't actually care about the Google input screen really, maybe they just said that because they made an assumption about how it would work, rather than explicitly wanting that exact thing. The end goal should be the important aspect.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a complete solution but a simple redirect to the google calendar page with path params might be helpful.

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20210528T065000Z/20210528T070000Z&text=cool+event

this will open google calendar UI with your date and event details.